# Windows 8.1 tablet-PC Blutooth Metro panel access shortcut

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth, tablet-pc

Is it possible to access this panel by a desktop shortcut?
It's ASUS Tablet! Read many instructions but didn't find any working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqrWy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Found the way at last! 
http://doitanyway.co.uk/how-to-put-a-bluetooth-onoff-tile-in-windows-8-1-on-tablet/
Characters to fill the body)))